# Java iterate directly through an array instead of array variable

Tags: java, for-loop

In some languages, Python, for example, one could directly iterate through an array:

```py
for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
    print(i)
```

I know Java can iterate through a variable by `for (type var : var2)`, then is it possible to skip the variable and directly iterate an array? such as:

```java
for (int i : [1, 2, 3, 4]) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: What is `[1, 2, 3, 4]` supposed to be? There are no list literals in Java.

Comment: `for (int i : new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4})`

Comment: @LutzHorn An array. In this case an array of integers. I use `[1, 2, 3, 4]` just as a demo.

Comment: You know how an array looks in Java? Do you want to know how an array is constructed or if there is a list literal in Java as there is in Python?

Comment: @JacobG. I see, that makes sense, thank you

Comment: @LutzHorn I guess you want to say `{` and `[`

Comment: I don't quite understand. The question is what *you* want to say. What is your question?

Comment: @LutzHorn Jocob solved it, I want to iterate through an array without having to create a variable.

Comment: You *are* creating an *array* if you follow the comment of Jacab. You just don't assign it to a name. Consider a method that returns the array. You can put the call to this method into `for (int i : theMethod())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to iterate through an array without having to create a
>   variable.

You need change the loop to this:

```
for (int i : new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4}) {
    // do something (4 iterations)
}
```

Credit: [Jacob G.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7294647/jacob-g)

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* want to avoid using bracket syntax you can also do:

```
for (int i : Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4)) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Which will effectively do the same thing as creating an `Array`, but instead you are iterating on a fixed size `List`.

**Note:**  This answer is mainly just for knowledge, and in practice you should not do this and prefer using `new int[]{}` over importing the `Arrays` library and boxing the values as a `List` unnecessarily.

The more traditional way you might see `asList()` used would be similar to:

```
Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: That it is fixed size is irrelevant, because you couldn't do anything to change its size even if it weren't (e.g. `for (int i : new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4))) {`. Also, note that this is boxing the values, only to immediately unbox them again.

Comment: @Andy Turner I don't recommend doing it this way, I just put it as alternative if he really insists of iterating in a way that _looks_ similar to Python.  It is nice to learn alternatives exist even if they are not good ones, in my opinion.

Comment: @Andy Turner Will do.

Answer (score 1):

You *could*, of course create the following utility:

```
class ArrayUtils {
    static int[] of(int... array) {
        return array;
    }
}
```

And then static-import this method, using `import static ArrayUtils.of`. Now you have a rather short expression:

```
for (int i : of(1, 2, 3, 4)) { ... }
```

I wouldn't, however, do this in a real-life scenario. I would instead just write an ol' skool

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) { ... }
```

or maybe

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 4)
```